TextInput component frozen when try to type something
I've created a child component for InputField and I used that component in my Signup.tsx page 4 times to make different type of InputField just like shown in the screenshot, but when I try to type something in my password field in IOS simulator both password and confirm-password field is frozen.
Image of Issue
FieldInput Image
<InputField placeholder="Name *" style={{ width: width * 0.7 }} key="name" defaultVal={name} onChange={(value : string, isValid : boolean) => {setErrorHas(!isValid); setName(value);}} />

<InputField placeholder="Mobile Number *" type="mobile" keytype="number-pad" defaultVal={mobile} key="mobile" style={{ width: width * 0.7 }} onChange={(value : string, isValid : boolean) => {setErrorHas(!isValid); setMobile(value);}} />

<InputField placeholder="New Password *" secure={true} key="password" defaultVal={password} style={{ width: width * 0.7 }} isIcon={true} icon={["eye-blocked", "eye"]} onChange={(value : string, isValid : boolean) => {setErrorHas(!isValid); setPassword(value);}} />

<InputField placeholder="Re-Enter Password *" secure={true} key="rePassword" defaultVal={repassword} style={{ width: width * 0.7 }} isIcon={true} icon={["eye-blocked", "eye"]} onChange={(value : string, isValid : boolean) => {setErrorHas(!isValid); setRepassword(value);}} />

the last two components I've called in Singup.tsx are some kind of event bubbling because when I console the callback arguments then I saw that by hitting keyboard in password field it's also called rePassword
InputField Component.tsx
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, TextInput, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import styles from './InputFieldStyle';
import Icomoon from 'react-native-icomoon';
import type { IconMoonProps } from 'react-native-icomoon';
import json from '../.././../../assets/fonts/selection.json';
import { COLORS } from "../../../../style/colorsStyle";
import { fontStyle } from "../../../../style/globalStyle";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

type IconProps = Omit<IconMoonProps, 'iconSet'>

function Icon({ name, ...restProps }: IconProps) {
  return <Icomoon iconSet={json} name={name} {...restProps} />
}

const InputField = ({ placeholder, style, type, keytype, secure, isIcon, icon, defaultVal, onChange } : any) : JSX.Element => {
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [secureText, setSecureText] = useState(false);
    const [iconName, setIconName] = useState('');

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(secure)
            setSecureText(secure)
        if(isIcon && icon && icon.length > 0)
            setIconName(icon[0])
    }, [])

    const handleInputChange = (value : string) => {
        let valid = true;
        switch(type && type == 'mobile') {
            case (value.length < 10 || value.length > 10):
                setError('Mobile Number should be 10 digits');
                valid = false;
                break;
            case (!value.match(/^\d{10}$/)):
                setError('Mobile Number only contains numeric value');
                valid = false;
                break;
            default :
                setError('');
                valid = true;
                break;
        }
        onChange(value, valid);
    }

    const changeIcon = () => {
        if(secure && icon && icon.length > 1){
            setSecureText(!secureText)
            setIconName(icon.indexOf(iconName) == 0 ? icon[1] : icon[0])
        }
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <View style={[
                styles.default,
                type == 'mobile' && styles.flexInput,
                isIcon && styles.flexInput,
                error != '' && {borderColor: 'red'}
            ]}>
                { type == 'mobile' && <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', width: 40, height: height*0.05, borderRightColor: COLORS.border, borderRightWidth: 1}}><Text style={styles.prefixLabel}>+91</Text></View> }
                <TextInput placeholder={placeholder} placeholderTextColor={COLORS.gray} secureTextEntry={secureText} keyboardType={keytype ? keytype : 'default'} defaultValue={defaultVal ? defaultVal : ''} style={[styles.input, {...style}]} maxLength={type == 'mobile' ? 10 : 100} onChangeText={handleInputChange}/>
                {isIcon && icon && icon.length > 0 && <TouchableOpacity onPress={changeIcon} activeOpacity={1}><Icon name={iconName} size={20} color={COLORS.gray} /></TouchableOpacity>}
            </View>
            {
                error != '' && <Text style={{color: 'red', fontFamily: fontStyle.regular, fontSize: 12, marginBottom: 5}}>{error}</Text>
            }
        </View>
    )
}

export default InputField;

InputField Component.ts Style
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import {COLORS} from '../../../../style/colorsStyle';
import { fontStyle } from "../../../../style/globalStyle";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const inputStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    default: {
        borderRadius: 6,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: COLORS.border,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
        marginVertical: 5,
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    prefixLabel: {
        color: COLORS.gray,
        fontFamily: fontStyle.regular
    },
    input: {
        height: height*0.05,
        width: '100%',
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        fontFamily: fontStyle.regular,
        color: COLORS.black,
        letterSpacing: 0.3,
        fontWeight: '600'
    },
    flexInput: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
});

export default inputStyle;

React Native Info :
System:
OS: macOS 14.4.1
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M2
Memory: 104.36 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell:
version: "5.9"
path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node:
version: 18.18.1
path: /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn:
version: 1.22.21
path: /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
npm:
version: 9.8.1
path: /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman:
version: 2024.01.22.00
path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods:
version: 1.15.2
path: /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms:
- DriverKit 23.4
- iOS 17.4
- macOS 14.4
- tvOS 17.4
- visionOS 1.1
- watchOS 10.4
Android SDK:
API Levels:
- "28"
- "30"
- "31"
- "33"
- "34"
Build Tools:
- 30.0.3
- 33.0.0
- 33.0.1
- 34.0.0
System Images:
- android-30 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a
- android-34 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
- android-34 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a
Android NDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2023.1 AI-231.9392.1.2311.11330709
Xcode:
version: 15.3/15E204a
path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java:
version: javac 21
path: /usr/bin/javac
Ruby:
version: 2.6.10
path: /usr/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
"@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
react:
installed: 18.2.0
wanted: 18.2.0
react-native:
installed: 0.73.4
wanted: 0.73.4
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
"react-native": Not Found
Android:
hermesEnabled: true
newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
hermesEnabled: true
newArchEnabled: false
I've create another component but it's behave same, I think it's just because of secureTextEntry but not sure that much.
